# Is it possible to put (GNU) assembler code for different archs into one source file?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

I have a short piece of assembler, that I want to keep in a single file for all supported architectures. One way to do that is to use inline assembly in a C file, but since there is no real C code around, I would rather like to use a (preprocessed) assembler file. Like:

```
    .file   "zsvjmp.S"

# Here comes the description what this code is supposed to do

    .globl  zsvjmp_
    .text

zsvjmp_:
#if defined (__i386__)
    # here comes the i386 specific assembler code
#elif defined (__arm__)
    @ here comes the arm specific assembler code
#endif
```

I am however not sure whether this works properly; for example comments are started with `#` in i386 assembler, while on arm they start with `@` - so how common comments would be handled? And maybe there are more pitfalls?

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Comments can be handled by using C comments which will be removed by the C preprocessor. However, I don't really see the point of this since you're going to have to conditionalize almost the entire file.

Comment: It is usually a better idea to have one source file per architecture.

Comment: @fuz do you have an explanation? Handling a single file is easier than having a dozen of them, and also in C you find files where most code is enclosed by `#ifdef`. What is special on assembler that it should be strictly avoided there?

Comment: @olebole Every platforms assembly language has different syntax and conventions. Making a polyglot is a futile exercise. C files with ifdef mazes are code smells, too.

Comment: The assembler is only ~5 lines long; IMO it is easier to understand one 100 LOC file than 10 files with all having the same comments/documentation repeated. And a "gcc zsvjmp.S" is easier than to determine the processor in the Makefile and to apply arch specific rules there: there is only *one* well-defined place to add/change an architecture, and not two or three. file names like `zsvjmp-i386.s`, `zsvjmp-x32.s`, `zsvjmp-ppcel.s` etc. also smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use gcc, and your assembly source file has the suffix `.S`, gcc will apply the C preprocessor to your assembly file before sending it to the assembler. Thus `#` can be used for preprocessor directives, because the preprocessor sees it first. The preprocessor also strips C-style comments (`/* */` and `//`), so you can use those regardless of the assembler you are using.

Comment: P.S. "It is usually a better idea to have one source file per architecture." --fuz

Comment: A problem are compiler directives. While `.type foo, @function` can be replaced with `.type foo, STT_FUNC`, I don't know a common replacement for `.section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits`.

Comment: @olebole That's one of the reason why you shouldn't do polyglots. Though, for this case there is a solution. You can find it in the gas manual.

Comment: Couldn't find this in the manual; could you be so kind to help out?